# How do I check for user role given events on Discord rewrite?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Each time a user is given a new role, I want the bot to check for the role's name, the user it was given to, and log that. I looked in the rewrite documentation but this is all I could find relating to role events which all seems to relate to the role being created, updated, or deleted, rather than given to someone:

```
on_guild_role_create()

on_guild_role_delete()

on_guild_role_update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event you're looking for is [`on_member_update(before, after)`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.on_member_update)

To check if the roles have been added, you would compare `before.roles` and `after.roles` and work out what was added, removed or changed.